# Windows Installer always says "Another program is being installed"

Tags: windows-installer

Somewhere some software install must have died.  Now when I try to install software, I get popup message from the Windows Installer saying "Another program is being installed.  Please wait until that installation is complete, and then try installing this software again.".

A search on serverfault brings up "Windows Installer Cleanup Tool" which Microsoft has stopped supporting.  Another search lead me to WiseFixer which wants $50 to fix my computer.

I don't mind paying some money to fix my computer but I no longer trust things I find via most product review sites or web searches.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? After all, it is a Windows machine.

Comment: Have you tried reregistering msiexec? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315346

Comment: To let Google catch up on this, the German error message reads "_Ein anderes Programm wird momentan installiert. Warten Sie, bis die andere Installation abgeschlossen ist, und wiederholen Sie anschließend die Installation dieser Software._".

Comment: In my case it was a process called "TiWorker.exe". No matter how often I killed "msiexec.exe" via Process Explorer, it keeps popping up, again. After I killed "TiWorker.exe" and _then_ killing "msiexec.exe", it did not pop up again.

Comment: solved it by searching and killing all task name that appear with "installer" in their name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open `regedit` and see if this key exists:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress
```

If so, remove it. Restart the *Windows Installer* service after removing the key.

Comment: I've seen regedit before but I don't remember where is is located.  Should I edit it as a text file or should I run regedit?

Comment: Start, Run, type 'regedit' and navigate the tree from there.

Comment: Someone who has to be told exactly how to run regedit probably **really shouldn't run regedit.**

Comment: Seems to have worked.  I also used System Mechanic to clean things up.  And I rebooted after I removed the key listed above.

Comment: How to stop it when `net stop msiserver` is unable to stop it?

Answer (score 11):

Fire up [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and hover your mouse over each instance of `msiexec.exe`. With a bit of luck you'll get the command line of what's installing which should give you some clues as to what it is.

[image: Process Explorer msiexec example]

I get this from time to time and it's my antivirus installing something which I can only guess is new definitions, because it happens frequently enough for me to notice.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is a basic response...but, do you have any pending windows updates that need to have their installation finalized via a reboot?

On a side-note, using Windows Installer Cleanup Tool was the biggest mistake I ever made. Just thought I'd throw that in. ;)

Comment: I've have rebooting this machine many times so there is no finalize with a reboot pending.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to try stopping the Windows Installer Service. That may resolve the problem in itself.
Quite possibly Windows is installing updates in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I had Acronis True Image (Home) running but didn't have the external drive attached where it wanted to make a backup.  Stopping all (4) Acronis services from running allowed me to install/uninstall.

It was an educated guess that this was the thing causing the "lock" on installing/uninstalling.  If you have installed software running as a service, you cold selectively stop/start each one to see if it helps.

NOTE: I tried all of the responses here, but none helped.